Vue3 handle dynamic computed call parameters within for loop without breaking syntax highlighting
In a Vue 3 component I'm trying to provide the indexes of 2 for loops as parameters of a method or computed value within my template section of my component.
I'm using these 2 parameters to retrieve the data for the specific cell of data.
The data is stored in a lookup table, and the key to the data is stored in the 2d array of rows and columns in actualGrid.
I'm using a computed function, to store the computed value based on the indexes. Honestly not sure if this is how computed functions are supposed to work. As when a computed value is calculated it is cached, till its inputs next change. So if the for loop iterates through the indexes [0][0], 0, 0. I would expect the computed value to have to be recalculated each time.
Is this how I should be performing a dynamic computed call within a for loop? My code works but my syntax highlighter hates this and doesnt work.
The implementation below breaks by syntax highlighter as soon as i put cellData() call on :isHeader=, if it is not a function call highlighting is normal
    <template v-for="(rowArr, rowIndex) in actualGrid" :key="rowIndex">
      <template v-for="(colEl, colIndex) in rowArr" :key="colIndex">
        <GridCellInputText
            :isHeader="
            cellData(rowIndex, colIndex).isHeader
            "
            :styles="
            cellData(rowIndex, colIndex).styles
            "
        />

  computed: {
    // also computed for reuse in template
    cellData() {
      return (cellRowIndex, cellColIndex) => {
        let key = this.actualGrid[cellRowIndex][cellColIndex]
        return this.dataMap[key]
      };
    },
  },

I'm using vue official language support tool for visual studio code.
Syntax highlighting on non computed property. This looks as expected:

Syntax highlighting on computed property. This is the issue. I'm wondering what the correct approach is then to implement this structure in vue


" as each new index pair changes the input to the computed property" - can you clarify? "My code works but my syntax highlighter hates this and doesnt work" - it's unknown what's the problem with the highlighter and what it is. Any way, blame it. It's inefficient at least to call cellData twice. Should be v-bind=cellData(rowIndex, colIndex).

Apologies, I've updated my post to show the change in the syntax highlighter based on using computed properties with and without passing params. I mainly took the syntax highlighter as an indication something was wrong.
I'm trying to understand how to properly implement the computed property when it has changing inputs.
So with the v-bind=cellData(rowIndex, colIndex) i should just pass this directly onto the child component?

What is the problem with the second case? Is it red ">" that suggests there's an error? There's no problem with your code, blame it on IDE, whatever it is.  v-bind=cellData(rowIndex, colIndex) is the same as :isHeader=... :styles=..., considering that this.dataMap[key] contains only 2 keys, which is unknown. Only that v-bind is more effective. There are no dedicated parametrized getters in vue, you could keep cellData the way it is, or make it a method, there's no much difference, but probably they will be treated differently by IDE. Any way, IDE is the problem
